# Rails 4 Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 535 #5.7.0 Authentication failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, actionmailer

I'm building a email list for a student organization at my University. The organization has around 6000 members and to avoid costs I've received permission to use the schools emails servers and they have created an account for me.

I have tested the the account using my mail client and everything seems to be working fine, but when I try to send through my `Rails 4` app I get the error:

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 535 #5.7.0 Authentication failed
```

I have it configured like so:

**application.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = 
{
    :address   => "smtp.school.edu",
    :port      => 25, 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
    :user_name => "account@school.edu",
    :password  => "mypassword", 
    :authentication => 'login',
    :domain => 'http://myapp.herokuapp.com/' 
}
```

Again the credentials are all correct, I have tested it through my mail client and have also sat down with the server admin to confirm everything looks right in my configuration as far as port and credentials.

I've been told the smtp server is "wide open to the public" and there is nothing blocking a connection and we have checked their logs and they haven't even seen an attempt to connect from my app.

Anyone have any clue what is going wrong here? Is there some setting I dont know about that could be off?

Comment: Can you post the logs from the action after the mail is sent  .

Comment: Also do keep checking the spam folder , as testing a certain functionality time and again is treated as spam by google .

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Im not using google.

Comment: In your mailer file  what is the email that you are using ?
make sure it's the same as

Check if the port is open or accessible,

Answer (score 6):

Try adding `openssl_verify_mode => 'none'` to your action mailer settings:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = 
{
    :address   => "smtp.school.edu",
    :port      => 25, 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
    :user_name => "account@school.edu",
    :password  => "mypassword", 
    :authentication => 'login',
    :domain => 'http://myapp.herokuapp.com/',
    :openssl_verify_mode => 'none'
}
```

Granted, we are using Rails 3, but this worked for me.  The issue for us was that our certificates are self-signed and the library Rails uses considers that to be a problem.
Here is an [article](http://davidroetzel.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/rails-3-actionmailer-tls-certificate-verification/) that talks about the option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I still get the same error message.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the smtp server using telnet or the like? That's how I figured out what was wrong with my configuration...

Comment: @Deekor hmm... do you think you could add what you did to connect via telnet to the question (scrubbed a bit of course)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the link to the reason.  This helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Should ":domain" point to "school.edu" instead of "herokuapp.com"?  I know when you set smtp for gmail via action_mailer settings, you have something like:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'gmail.com',
    :user_name            => 'example@gmail.com',
    :password             => 'example_password',
    :authentication       => 'login',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: hmmm doesnt seem to make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `setup_mail.rb` in the folder `config/initializers/` and put the code:-

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address   => "smtp.school.edu",
  :domain => 'myapp.herokuapp.com',
  :port      => 25,
  :user_name => "account@school.edu",
  :password  => "mypassword", 
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "myapp.herokuapp.com"
```

Comment: how is this any different than what I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Should the domain contain "http://" ?

Comment: domain shouldnt matter according to the server admin

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by following steps.

```
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'mysite.com',
    user_name: myemail@gmail.com,
    password: mypassword,
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

As google will try to block your sign-in if you have turned off access for less secure apps in your accounts settings. Therefore, follow this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and "**Turn on**" access for less secure apps.