# email within confirmable devise is sent automatically ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

Using devise confirmable trick to verify the user account with the email, I add in the `User` model.

I put

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

So I add a registration form :

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, html: {class: "form"}, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

When submitting this form, is the email confirmation sent automatically ? or do I need to customize it ? (because I get no email sent)

Comment: setup mail configuration as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735206/rails-4-netsmtpauthenticationerror-535-5-7-0-authentication-failed/25884665#25884665

Comment: Have you configured your `action_mailer.default_url_options`?