# why is devise not sending email via gmail smtp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for authentication. It provides a forgot password link. When i send email then the email is not sent. Following is the settings i have used. Can you tell me why gmail is not sending the email? I have also turned on "allow less secure app to send email" and i have also enabled imap in gmail setting.

application.rb has the following setting.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {


  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :domain => 'mail.google.com',
  :port => 587,
  :user_name => 'validemail@gmail.com',
  :password => 'validpassword',
  :authentication => 'login',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true


}
```

development.rb has

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: '127.0.0.1'}


  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

After sending the email i get the following text in the console.

```
Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 215.2ms
Sent mail to validemail@gmail.com (1097.6ms)
Date: Thu, 29 Dec 2016 09:50:41 +0000
From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
To: validemail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5864dc7161acb_173921a07788707d@kofhearts-rubyonrails-3267120.mail>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello validemail@gmail.com!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://127.0.0.1/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=WQxYad91mPghMxaurYA5">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

Redirected to https://rubyonrails-kofhearts.c9users.io/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 1965ms (ActiveRecord: 14.7ms)
```

**UPDATE:**

I am just following this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEk0Jp2dThc

Send email is not working with the settings that are specified in this video.

Comment: May be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735206/rails-4-netsmtpauthenticationerror-535-5-7-0-authentication-failed/25884665#25884665

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question, but I gave up on using smtp through gmail. I now use `sendinblue`, they have an smpt service which is free for about 300 emails a day. Also a nice ruby gem so it's quite easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

Enabling **less secure apps** in my account settings worked for me.

Google Account settings > Signing in to Google > scroll down to the bottom

Turn on allow less secure apps. Try sending the email again.

Answer (score 0):

That's should work.
Maybe you could also turn on `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`
in `config/environments/development.rb`.
It's easier to debug.

Maybe you forget to set `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` in `config/environments/development.rb`?

Comment: thanks but even after adding the perform_deliveries setting and raise_delivery_errors flag the email is not sending. I have updated my post above with the console message that is printed after i click on "send me reset password instructions" that is supposed to send email to the provided email.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "gmail.com",  
  :user_name            => "myinfo@gmail.com",  
  :password             => "secret",  
  :authentication       => "plain"
  # :enable_starttls_auto => true # I don't have this, but it should work anyway 
}
```

it it's sent maybe you don't receive it because of the spam filter, first thing to check:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "myinfo@gmail.com"
  # ...
end
```

You also check your `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` in your gmail..

include these line of codes on your `development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'your server' } # ex. localhost:3000
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true # to raise error if smtp has error on setup
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

Comment: thanks i added from and that also didnt work. i also checked the spam and the message is not there.

Comment: @user734861 ok fine.. now you must enable you "Forwarding and POP/IMAP"..

Comment: i have enabled imap. should i also enable pop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131780/discussion-between-user734861-and-karthick-nagarajan).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are working with Gmail you should activate permission to
   externals apps send email through SMTP.
2. **In development mode Rails does not send emails**, you should **run** Rails in production   `rails s -e production` or turn on `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`
3. do not forget to use `mail().deliver` or for Rails 5+ `mail().delivery_now`

look you this is my SMTP configuration

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => ENV['mailer_address'],
    :port                 => ENV['mailer_port'],
    :user_name            => ENV['mailer_username'],
    :password             => ENV['mailer_password'],
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

this is my Class Mailer

```
def send_email
 mail(to: "example@email.com", subject: 'not reply this message').deliver
end
```

I call that function from my controller. If you got any error you should print it to check what is the problem.

```
begin
  myMailer.send_email
rescue  Exception => e
  flash[:error] = "Imposible sent email, #{e.inspect}"
end
```

Comment: thanks jeff but i have enabled pop, imap and also enabled less secure apps to access gmail permission. Still with the above settings the email is not getting delivered.

Comment: can you create a mailer testing if it is working?, which Rails version are you working?