# G-suite email settings not worked while sending email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I used G-suite email setting for sending emails from Rails application. This is my client G-suite email. Generally I used my gmail settings and it's work but G-suite email settings not work. Below code:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address              => "smtp-relay.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :user_name            => "info@XXXX.com",
   :password             => "XXXXXX",
   :authentication       => "plain",
   :domain               => "gmail.com",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I used `address: "smtp.gmail.com"` as well but not working.

I got `error: SMTP: authentication failed` and sometimes nothing but not received email.

Anyone have idea or same experience solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is this configuration in gmail that **COULD** be the cause of the problem. I am not sure it would result with an `error: SMTP: authentication failed`

this is the [guide](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) to allow the unsafe apps

> ## Change your settings to allow less secure apps into your account.
>
> We don't recommend this option because it can make it easier for someone to break into your account. If you want to allow access anyway, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to the "[Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)" section of my Account.
> 2. Turn on **Allow less secure apps**. (Note: If your administrator has locked less secure app account access, this setting is hidden.)

also I found similar post for this problem, for example a similar issue was solved in this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735206/rails-4-netsmtpauthenticationerror-535-5-7-0-authentication-failed#25794003)

Comment: Thanks for response but its already done but still facing issue.

Comment: @harsh4u an issue is you are using `ENV` variable as password, are you sure it is working?

Comment: I put static username and password.

Comment: `Try adding openssl_verify_mode => 'none' to your action mailer settings:` did you search on stackoverflow and did you try the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735206/rails-4-netsmtpauthenticationerror-535-5-7-0-authentication-failed#25794003 how does your `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` looks like in your `production.rb`

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&visit_id=1-636449592727814665-2485432046&rd=3

Answer (score 1):

These settings worked for me:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com", 
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => 'info@example.com', # Change this to the email you're sending from
 :password             => 'your_password_goes_here', # Change this to your password
 :authentication       => "plain",
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

One extra tip. By default: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false` set to `true` so you can see any error messages in your browser/console

NOTE: in order for the mailer to work with any google email account you **must** have 'Allow less secure apps' turned on.

To do this, first go to the G-Suite **admin** console and turn on Security -> Advanced Security Settings and check the radio button: "Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps"

Now login to your G-Suite **user** account, go to My Account -> Sign-in & security. At the bottom you'll see Allow less secure apps. Turn that on.

You're good to go!

Comment: This works in 2019. I don't know the state of the gsuite docs when the question was asked, but they now reflect `smtp.gmail.com` as the address (as this answer does) vs `smtp-relay.gmail.com`